# dynamicaly adding controls in android onbutton click

Tags: android, controls

This is what i am doing in coding i want to create controls on button click. The number of times the user will click i want to add controls for the same number of time..
 I have to add these controls in relative layout. which i had already created in xml layout with one set of controls already in it.. and want to make it working for more controls if user want to edit.

```
    View DynamicView= new View(this);
    DynamicView.setId(123);                
    DynamicView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
```

The following is XML layout code.

```
<View
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="1dp"
           android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

problems:-
1) dont want to give ids this way :(

```
  DynamicView.setId(123);
```

want to assign such ids as we can assign in xml layout

```
android:id="@+id/spnrIngredients1"
```

2) how to give values for relative layouts in coding such as

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvIngredientsName"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvIngredientsName"
android:layout_below="@id/tvIngredientsName"
android:layout_above="@id/tvIngredientsName"
```

3) how to give values for background colors.
it is not accepting hexadecimal codes or something else.. what type of int values it is asking for..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) Use the `LayoutParams` to set the rules for placing the views in the `RelativeLayout`:

```
Button b = new Button(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, viewID);
b.setLayoutParams(lp);
b.setText("Added at Bottom");
mParent.addView(b, lp);
```

The above code will place the `Button` bellow the view with the id `viewID`.

3) `setBackgroundColor()`(I think this is the method you are using) requires an int representing the `Color`, you can set it in that method this ways:

```
Color.RED 
Color.parse(Color.parseColor("#0077cc"))
android.R.color.black
```

1) You could set your ids in a `values/ids.xml` file and later set them to your views and then refer the views by those ids:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="myfirstid" />    
</resources>
```

Now you can use the id `R.id.myfirstid` in your code(I don't know if this is what you want).
**NOTE:** 
I don't know if this is recommended.

Comment: thanks a lot especially for that "addrule" and storing "ids" in separate xml file.. i was really looking for some thing such